# Problem \usepackage{graphicx}, doesn't work

Tags: graphics, errors, texworks

I'm using TEXWORKS, and I want to add a image (.pnj) in my latex. I put:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

But gives me this error: ! LaTeX Error: File 'epstopdf-base.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:

What does it mean? How can I do to add a simple image?
Which command should I add to insert the correct package?
Thank you

Comment: Don't open a new question, edit your question from yesterday. And Texworks is not a tex system, it is simply an editor. Your tex system is something like texlive or miktex. If you don't know what you use: show the complete log-file of your example.

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.5)

Comment: to install something for such a texlive you will have to use the historic repository. See here under "Past Releases" https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

Comment: but so there is no way to add images without having to install this?

Comment: If your texsystem is incomplete and an important sty is missing you should install it. Or install directly a current, complete texlive.

Comment: Why not just upgrade to latest version?

Comment: can you advise me which is the latest version?